# Custom admin module seperate form for edit and new

Tags: magento-1.8, module, edit-order

I am adding custom admin module for magento 1.8.
I have joined two table one is core_store_group and another one is my custom flat table
Its working fine, In new form I have 2 fields select box and file field, I am adding store_group_id and CSV file content to my custom flat table by iterating each time for CSV content.

Yes Now also its working fine.
I am facing problem in edit.
I am using same form to edit the product. That I don't want.
I need to display all the content while editing in two fields one is **select**
That is showing correct answer, second field while editing instead of file field I need to display text area to display data.

Following is my form code which display one select field and file field for both while edit and new

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $foundation = Mage::registry('foundation_data');
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('foundation_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('foundation')->__('Foundation Members')));

        $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('Select Store'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'store_id',
          'values'   => Mage::helper('foundation')->getStoreOptionValues(true),
          ));
        $fieldset->addField('file', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('CSV'),
          'class'     => 'desable',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'file',
        ));
        $this->setForm($form);
        $form->setValues($foundation->getData());
        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFoundationData()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFoundationData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFoundationData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('foundation_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('foundation_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

My question is how to display different form while edit and new?

Comment: I suggest you to add piece of code, that you are using

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, But you can try something like this:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $foundation = Mage::registry('foundation_data');
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('foundation_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('foundation')->__('Foundation Members')));

        $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('Select Store'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'store_id',
          'values'   => Mage::helper('foundation')->getStoreOptionValues(true),
          ));
          if(($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))!=''){
          $fieldset->addField('textarea', 'textarea', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('form')->__('TextArea'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'title',
          'onclick' => "",
          'onchange' => "",
          'value'  => '<b><b/>',
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => false,
          'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
          'tabindex' => 1
        ));
}
else{

$fieldset->addField('file', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('CSV'),
          'class'     => 'desable',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'file',
        ));
}
 $this->setForm($form);
        $form->setValues($foundation->getData());
        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFoundationData()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFoundationData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFoundationData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('foundation_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('foundation_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the form is on edit mode by using below code `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');`

It should return you the 'id', when you will edit any entry . On the basis of this id, you can make checks in "_prepareForm()" and can show the textarea and set values in 'values' tag of that field . 
But first be sure that when you are uploading CSV file, you are saving its content in database as text, not it as a file.